# How to define global hotkey in C++/CX XAML App

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I'm trying to add support for global hotkey in my C++/Cx UWP App and I don't know how to do it.
I cannot find specific event/handler for this. Moreover, registerHotKey from winuser.h seems to be unavailable under UWP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google "uwp hotkey" to find relevant hits.  Stefan Wick's approach is, erm, what it takes.

Comment: I saw it, but ...
Is there no simpler solution?

Comment: If that made you think "whoa, I probably shouldn't do this" then you got to understand UWP a bit better.  Google "winrt process lifecycle" for the basics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shortcuts in UWP can be set via `Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated`.

This is a C# code to call `Ctrl` + `Q`, maybe it helps you.

```cs
public class MainPage
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += AccelertorKeyActivedHandle;
}

private void AccelertorKeyActivedHandle(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
       var ctrl= Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
       if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
       {
           if (args.VirtualKey == VirtualKey.Q)
           {
              // code here
           }
       }

    }
}
```

Best regards.